# Gradient becoming larger and larger while implementing gradient descent

Tags: regression, machine-learning, generalized-linear-model, python, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement the gradient descent in Python. The data is that of housing prices and I want to predict the house price. But the problem is that the gradient is becoming larger and larger until Python cannot process it anymore.

How can I debug or fix this?

#### Code:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
from numpy import genfromtxt

train_file = sys.argv[1]
dev_file = sys.argv[2]
learning = sys.argv[3]

X_train = np.genfromtxt(train_file, dtype='f', delimiter = ',', skip_header 
= 1,filling_values  = 0, usecols = 
(3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,17,18,19,20))
y_train = np.genfromtxt(train_file, dtype='f', delimiter = ',', skip_header 
= 1,filling_values = 0, usecols = (2))

training_examples = X_train.shape[0]
total_featues = X_train.shape[1]

Wprime = np.asarray([0]*total_featues)
W = Wprime.reshape(-1,1)

k = 0
while k<total_featues :
    i=0
    temp_sum = 0
    #print(X_train[i][k])
    while i< training_examples:
        A = Wprime
        B = X_train[i]
        #print(y_train[i])
        f = abs(np.dot(A,B)-y_train[i])
        #print("this is f"+str(f))
        f = f*X_train[i][k]
        temp_sum = temp_sum + f
        i=i+1
    print("this is temp sum " + str(temp_sum))
    update = temp_sum*0.0001/training_examples
    print("this is update "+str(update))
    Wprime[k] = Wprime[k] - update
    print(Wprime)
    k = k+1
```

Answer (score 0):

A common problem with GD is overstepping (at least that's how I remember the name): you try to get closer and closer to the minimum point of the penalty function, but your step size is too large and now you just go on and make more steps, getting far away from optimum. My suggestion is this: while you see your penalty decreasing it's all good` once it starts to increase, invert your direction and reduce your learning factor (e.g $\alpha^*=0.5\alpha$) and so you solve the divergence situation.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I know the problem now. I was not scaling the data. Some of the data points were in the order of 10^6-7 while the others were ones and zeros.